# Python. Как обратиться к полученным данным из полей ввода?

Tags: python, tkinter

Полученные данные мне нужно добавить в БД, как можно обратиться к тексту полей ввода и `combobox` и вывести их?

```
self.entry_description = ttk.Entry(self)
self.entry_description.place(x=200,y=50)
self.entry_money = ttk.Entry(self)
self.entry_money.place(x=200,y=110)

self.combobox = ttk.Combobox(self, values=(u'Доходы',u'Расходы'),state='readonly')
self.combobox.current(0)
self.combobox.place(x=200,y=80)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
entry_value = self.entry_money.get()
combobox_vale = self.combobox.get()
```